# Populating dropdown via foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to populate a dropdown on my razor page with info from the database(My website is for document upload/download). When they are uploading a file, it asks for vendor Id as this is the foreign key linking my 'Files' and 'Vendor(user)' together.

In the dropdown I want them to be able to select the vendor name, but in the files db - the vendorId gets entered.

I could populate it manually with the following code:

```
 <select asp-for="Files.VendorId">
                <option value="3950">Girvan Early Growers Ltd</option>
 </select>
```

But at one point we may have anything up to 50 vendors, so not ideal.

Below I will include my page model and my cshtml page for this to see if it helps.

PageModel:

```
using FarmersPortal.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.Internal;

namespace FarmersPortal.Pages
{
    [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly FarmersPortal.Data.filedbContext _context;

    public CreateModel(FarmersPortal.Data.filedbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Data.Vendor> VendorList { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Data.Vendor> Vendores { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Vendores = _context.Vendors.ToList();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Data.File Files { get; set; }
    public Data.Vendor Vendors { get; set; }

    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Files.Add(Files);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

}


}
```

.cshtml:

```
@page
@model FarmersPortal.Pages.CreateModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('hero-range-1.jpg');
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>

<h1 style="color: white">Create</h1>

<h4 style ="color: white">Files</h4>
<hr/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Files.Number" class="control-label" style="color: white"></label>
            <input asp-for="Files.Number" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Files.Number" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Files.FileType" class="control-label" style="color: white"></label>
                <input asp-for="Files.FileType" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Files.FileType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Files.VendorId" class="control-label" style="color: white"></label>
                <input asp-for="Files.VendorId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Files.VendorId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Files.Haulier" class="control-label" style="color: white"></label>
                <input asp-for="Files.Haulier" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Files.Haulier" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Files.Comments" class="control-label" style="color: white"></label>
                <input asp-for="Files.Comments" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Files.Comments" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <select asp-for="Files.VendorId">
                <option value="3950">Girvan Early Growers Ltd</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }



}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: There is a tag helper for dropdown `asp-items`. `<select asp-for="Files.VendorId" asp-items="Vendores">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, In `Vendor` table, There are `Id`, `Name` and other properties, So If you want DropdownList show 'Name' as text, 'Id' as value, You can refer to this code:

```
public void OnGet()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>();

            Vendores = _context.Vendors.ToList();

            foreach (var item in Vendores)
            {
                test.Add(new SelectListItem {Text=item.Name,Value = item.Id.ToString() });
            }

            ViewData["demo"] = test;
            
        }
```

**In the View**

```
<select asp-for="Files.VendorId" asp-items="@ViewData["demo"]"></select>
```

Then the `dropdownlist` will show name but pass id.

You can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I may of worded my question wrong, I have a Files table with a FK from the Vendor table(id), So i need to insert the vendor Id into the files table, but I want them to be able to select by the vendor name which is in the vendor table.

Comment: Yeah, For example, Your  vendor table has data  like `{id=1,Name="AAAA"},{id=2,Name="BBBB"},{id=2,Name="CCCC"}, ........`, In the method i provided, Dropdownlist  only will show options: `AAAA,BBBB,CCCC........`, When select AAAA, Only the id of AAAA will bind to  `Files.VendorId`. I hope i  am not  misunderstand your question.

Comment: Ah right that makes more sense, I'm getting an error on the @ViewData part that says object cannot convert to SelectListItem - do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Megan Paterson, Sorry, you need to convert it to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, So chagne your code like this `asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["demo"])"`

Comment: So just to confirm, inside my page model I should have this:    `List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>();

            Vendores = _context.Vendors.ToList();

            foreach (var item in Vendores)
            {
                test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text=item.VendorName, Value = item.Id.ToString() });
            }
            ViewData["demo"] = test;` and in my view I should have this: `<select asp-for="Files.VendorId" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["demo"])"></select>`

Comment: @Megan Paterson, Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249073/discussion-between-megan-paterson-and-xinran-shen).