# Dropdown won't send info to db

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dropdown, razor-pages

In one of my previous questions, I asked how I would approach populating a dropdown on my razor page by pulling info from the database. See my question here: [Populating dropdown via foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74192464/populating-dropdown-via-foreign-key)

I was advised to do this by adding the following to my PageModel:

```
public List<Data.Vendor> Vendores { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>();
            //List<Data.File> files = new List<Data.File>();

        Vendores = _context.Vendors.ToList();

        foreach (var item in Vendores)
        {
            test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.VendorName, Value = item.Id.ToString() });
        }
        ViewData["demo"] = test;
}
```

and on the .cshtml adding the following:

```
<select asp-for="Files.VendorId" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["demo"])"></select>
```

But when submitting the form in which I want to save the Dropdown selection, when it gets to my Postasync:

```
[BindProperty]
    public Data.File Files { get; set; }
    public Data.Vendor Vendors { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        
        _context.Files.Add(Files);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

The data for that field doesn't get passed through.

If you need to see the full PageModel and .cshtml files I can add them.

I've recorded a video of me going through the process and showing that Vendor Id is null which means nothing is passing through:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CxObYQ9czs4OOJYCyr5OMmu-64X9iThz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sure, could you please share how you are sending the request and the details `PageModel and .cshtml files`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I've created a folder which includes the cshtml page, the page model and a video of me showing that the vendor id is null when going through the process: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1skzWfuMwQ_q7wAx5qiODPIEYgb8OHyoP?usp=sharing

Comment: When you set a breakpoint at `[BindProperty] public Data.File Files { get; set; }` and after the code run into OnPostAsync action, Does the `VendorId` property in Files have a value? I am not sure if it bind value successfully.

Comment: @XinranShen No it doesn't have a value - and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @Megan Paterson, please check the answer I update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I checking the code in `Create.cshtml`, I find the reason why `VendorId` can't be bind to the model.

In your Create.cshtml, you have the code:

```
//......

<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Files.VendorId" class="control-label" style="color: white"></label>
     <input asp-for="Files.VendorId" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="Files.VendorId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

//......

<select asp-for="Files.VendorId" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["demo"])"></select>

//........
```

Because they all use `asp-for="Files.VendorId"` to bind value, So they will generate the same name : `Files.VendorId` in html.

If there are multiple input attributes with the same name in the form, It will only bind the value of the first input attribute.

In your video, you don't  write any value in VendorId input tag, So `VendorId`  property in Files will not bind any value

[image]

You can just delete this input attribute and then `Files.VendorId`  will bind the value of dropdown list successfully.

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you! I haven't used ASP.NET in a few years so didn't realise this was the case.

Comment: I also write an answer in the link you provided in your question, I think it is the answer about that question, Do you have any 
doubt with my answer in that question?

Comment: No Ive just marked it as the answer to that one as well, thank you.